# Strange table alignment behavior in FF/Chrome

Tags: css, xhtml

I've just isolated a strange behavior in FF3.5 and Chrome 10 which explains why some of my tables aren't aligning as I expect.

When a CSS margin is set on the table (or via a general * selector) the align attribute no longer works.

I realise that align is deprecated now and that we should all be setting table alignment using the text-align style of the container, but sometimes it is still handy when you need different alignments of various content within a containing div.

IE (for once) seems to be the regular guy and is unaffected by the margin setting.  Check it out at:
http://www.songtricks.com/AlignBug.html

Here's the code - any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
</head>

<body>

        <table border="1" width="50%" align="center" style="margin:0px;">
        <tr>
            <td>Table with style="margin:0px;"</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <table border="1" width="50%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Table with no style</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What sort of an answer do you expect to get? What is logical when you set `align="center"` **and** `margin:0`?

Comment: Dude. Styles are applied in the order they are read. First you set center then you set margin:0px. IE is playing with you when talking about margins (as it ussually does).
Don't blame the other guys.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. @Kobi, why is the combination illogical?  Margin has no meaning unless you first know the alignment context.  @Alfabravo, I tried swapping the align and style attributes, but the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure how the align attribute works but it looks like when you apply a margin-top or margin-bottom to the style it doesn't seem to effect it. Only if you change the margin left and right properties it causes this bug. My guess is that the align property works the same as margin:0 auto. when I added auto for the left and right margins you get the desired outcome.

```
<table border="1" width="50%" style="margin:0px auto;">
    <tr>
        <td>Table with style="margin:0px;"</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, locrizak you are right. And in this case the align="center" attribute is no longer needed at all. Maybe they internally map to the same routine and that is why I was getting a conflict. I guess I should just stop using the align attribute and instead use auto margins whenever I want self-aligning content.